# Get substring from string using regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, substring

```
ex = "g4net:HostName=abc}\n Unhandled Exception: \nSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an";
puts ex[/Unhandled Exception:(.*?):/,0]
```

`/Unhandled Exception:(.*?):/` should match `\nSystem.NullReferenceException` (as tested in rubular) but it keeps displaying no result.

[image]

I'm new to ruby. Please help how can I extract a match for `/Unhandled Exception:(.*?):/` from given string

Comment: Rubular interprets your `\n` literally. You have to insert the lines separately to get the same behavior: http://rubular.com/r/MOdKAd2Xnl. Hint: `.` only matches newlines if the `m` flag is set.

Comment: If you want to match the text, use positive lookbehind: `puts ex[/(?<=Unhandled Exception:).*?:/m]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the regex in multiline mode should solve the issue:

```
(?m)Unhandled Exception:(.*?):
```

Code:

```
re = /Unhandled Exception:(.*?):/m
str = 'g4net:HostName=abc}
 Unhandled Exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby (and most other languages) use regular expression dialects which do not match newline characters with `.` by default. In Ruby you can use the `m` (multiline) modifier:

```
matchinfo = ex.match(/Unhandled Exception: (.*)/m)
# Allow "." to match newlines ------------------^
matchinfo[1] # => "\nSystem.NullRef..."
```

You can also use the character class `[\s\S]` instead of `.` for similar effect, without the need for the multiline modifier:

```
matchinfo = ex.match(/Unhandled Exception: ([\s\S]*)/)
# Really match *any* character -------------^----^
matchinfo[1] # => "\nSystem.NullRef..."
```

Comment: I'm glad to see you explain what the multiline modifier does. Though it's straightforward, there seems to be a lot of confusion about it. I've not seen `[\s\S]` before. I guess `[\w\W]` and `[\d\D]` would have the same effect.